# How to create sticky news item(s) in Plone 4

Tags: plone

How can I create sticky news items? Our homepage features a news collection (news items housed in folder) with certain criteria selected (published, tags, published date; reverse order). The homepage news gets updated just about everyday; however on occasion there are 1 or 2 news items that need to stay at the top of the news list (collection) for an extended period of time. How can I do this?

I searched the Plone User Manual and Plone site; tried several collection configurations; looked at addons like ListingPages and Plumi but neither appear to have the feature I'm looking for, and have searched the web for "sticky content" "sticky news item" and have not found a solution. If anyone knows how to do this and wouldn't mind sharing, I really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

- add a second collection in hp for featured news
- add a news item with a tag "featured"
- copy all criteria from the first collection to the new one and add a criterion on tag and select as tag "featured"

Then when you want a news item to be removed from the list, just remove the "featured" tag from it.

Alternatively you could customize your news item workflow and add a new state "featured" (the rest of the process is pretty the same).

Comment: These are both great methods; IMHO the workflow method is probably a bit easier to understand/use for day-to-day content editors.

Comment: I was using the first approach, but then realised that we would possibly have duplicates between collections, and there is no easy way (I know about) to exclude items from a collection that have a certain tag (i.e. "featured" in this case), 
so I would go for either the workflow suggestion or collective.sticky below

Answer (score 2):

collective.flag gives you the opportunity to mark an item as a special object, which makes semantically more sense than using a tag/keyword or workflow-state for distinction, I think.

Display and sorting can be done via collections (as Giaccomo also wrote), I recommend ContentWellPortlets to place portlets where you need them.

Answer (score 2):

No release yet but I just came across davisagli's "collective.sticky": https://github.com/davisagli/collective.sticky/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at this old blog post: [Beyond News Items: the need for news industry standards in Plone](http://hvelarde.blogspot.com/2007/12/beyond-news-items-need-for-news.html).

We've been working on [collective.nitf](https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf), a new Dexterity-based content type to solve this kind of issues. It's pretty ready for production on sites using Plone 4.1 but right now we are in the middle of some minor refactoring.

I will release it next week as soon as we complete the move of some code to another package and change the name of a field.

Answer (score 0):

afaik there is no way to create what you call sticky news in stock plone.

you could try soring by effective-date (newest on top) and set the effecitve date manually for your sticky news.
set a time <= now and > than the creation date of the newest newsitem that should not be sticky.

unfortunately this means touching your sticky notes each time you add a new news item.
or set the effective-date of your new newsitems so its before your sticky news and after the newest non-sticky news.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. It's an ok short-term solution. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

It's an ashamingly outdated method but hey It Still Works™: you could use [Products.CMFPublicator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CMFPublicator/) to achieve what you want. Have a look at it and reply here if you have any doubts.

Another old-aged solution would be using [Products.CMFContentPanels](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CMFContentPanels/). You can even try a combination of both!

Comment: I was wondering if this is what it would take — thought I'd ask here first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to sticky news item: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.stickyitem